# Python Unit Test Coverage and Caller function coverage

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, test-coverage

I'm using Python 3.7, Unittest, moto for boto3 to create unit tests for my application. I find a problem with the coverage report generaged by Coverage.
those files where I put functions and create unit tests for them have a good coverage percentage, which makes sense,
but those files where I call tested functions remains 0% tested, which makes no sense for me.

say I have function A and function B in a file called utility.py. with unit tests I have 100% test coverage for utility.py.

I remember for C and Java, in this case, the file application will have a teste coverage already, if i'm not wrong.

now I create a file called application.py and I call function A and function B with a couple of line to chaine their results and do some calculates.

for me, the file application.py should have some teste coverage, since those lines calling function A and function B are tested.

Is there a tool which can show the percentage of lines tested in the file application.py, especially indicate if a called function has been tested or not?

thanks in advance.